# c++ : force std::string to be casted to string_view than to a template

Tags: c++

I have the following class declaration :

```
class MyClass {
public :
    template <typename StringContainer>
    explicit MyClass(const StringContainer&)
    {
        std::cout << "String container ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    explicit MyClass(std::string_view)
    {
        std::cout << "string_view ctor" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Templated constructor version was implemented to deal with stl containers with std::string. For the snipped below I'd like to call `string_view` ctor but for some reason a templated version is used.

```
int main() {
    std::string tmp("a");
    MyClass test(tmp);

    return 0;
}
```

What is the right way to cast `std::string` to be used with `std::string_view` ctor?

Comment: `tmp` is a `std::string&`, and not a `std::string_view`, so the template version is a perfect match, and the `string_view` overload would require 1 user defined conversion.

Comment: You may be interested in the notes for `std::string::assign` overload#9 here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign `template < class T >
constexpr basic_string& assign( const T& t );` "This overload only participates in overload resolution if `std::is_convertible_v<const T&, std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>>` is true and `std::is_convertible_v<const T&, const CharT*>` is false."

Comment: @MooingDuck so you suggest checking whether a template is convertible to std::string_view ?

Comment: That's what I did, yes https://github.com/Ambeco/mpd/blob/master/SmallContainers/small_string.hpp#L410. Alternatively limit the existing template to NOT work with classes that convert to `std::string_view`, which forces those classes to use your `std::string_view` overload.

Answer (score 1):

Your template constructor is picked because it is a better match for `std::string` than the `std::string_view` constructor is.  `StringContainer` gets deduced as `std::string`, making `MyClass(const StringContainer&)` an *exact* match for `tmp`, whereas `MyClass(std::string_view)` would require an implicit conversion from `std::string` to `std::string_view`.

If you want the `std::string_view` constructor called, you could do that conversion explicitly, eg:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::string tmp("a");
    MyClass test(std::string_view{tmp});

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/YBzGSmlmM)

Otherwise, you could add another constructor just for `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public :
    template <typename StringContainer>
    explicit MyClass(const StringContainer&)
    {
        std::cout << "String container ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    explicit MyClass(const std::string&)
    {
        std::cout << "String ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    explicit MyClass(std::string_view)
    {
        std::cout << "string_view ctor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string tmp("a");
    MyClass test(tmp); // calls MyClass(const std::string&)

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/H16m8m7GO)

Or, you could try using SFINAE to make the template constructor match with anything that is not `std::string` or `std::string_view` (my SFINAE-fu is not so good, so I won't try to provide an example here).

Or, you could make the template only match with *actual containers* of `std::string` elements, that way passing in a `std::string` can match only with `std::string_view`, eg:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public :
    template < template <typename, typename...> typename StringContainer >
    explicit MyClass(const StringContainer<std::string>&)
    {
        std::cout << "String container ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    explicit MyClass(std::string_view)
    {
        std::cout << "string_view ctor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string tmp("a");
    MyClass test(tmp); // calls MyClass(std::string_view)

    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    MyClass test2(vec); // calls MyClass(const StringContainer&)

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/as5_ymCtD)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SFINAE to exclude types convertible to `std::string_view` in your template constructor:

```
template <typename StringContainer, 
          std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible_v<StringContainer, std::string_view>, int> = 0> // #include <type_traits>
explicit MyClass(const StringContainer&)
{
    std::cout << "String container ctor" << std::endl;
}
```

With C++20, you can write

```
template <typename StringContainer> 
    requires (!std::convertible_to<StringContainer, std::string_view>) // #include <concepts>
explicit MyClass(const StringContainer&) 
{
    std::cout << "String container ctor" << std::endl;
}
```